# URL rewriting with two parameters using .htaccess and Apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have below code in .htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/page/([0-9]+)/{0,1}$ themes/tema_2/category.php?slug=$1&page=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

I have problem with second parameter "page"... When I do `$_GET['slug']` i got something like this: `fudbal/page/2` if my url is like this: `http://exmpl.com/category/fudbal/page/2`.

So `$_GET['slug']` returns all after `category/` like it's slug.

I need to achieve this: When I echo `$_GET['slug']` to echo `fudbal` and When I echo `$_GET['page']` to echo `2`.

Comment: It is because of this: RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/?$ themes/tema_2/category.php?slug=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

I have this above that third line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tweak your regex to fix your issue like this:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/?$ themes/tema_2/category.php?slug=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/page/(\d+)/?$ themes/tema_2/category.php?slug=$1&page=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: It does not work when is **RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ themes/tema_2/category.php?slug=$1 [NC,L,QSA]** above it...

Comment: You need to replace your rule with this rule. If you have more rules in .htaccess then show them here. Also tell what is the full URL you're using to test this.

Comment: All I have is this http://pastebin.com/ET6khw6M

Try it here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: `$_GET['page']` should definitely work for `www.example.com/category/football/page/2`. Are you sure there is no other .htaccess or no other rule?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure... Would you like to PM me on email or facebook?